# How to make an effect of expandable UICollectionView cell in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view 3x3.
Item (collection cell) contains some icon and label.
I want some additional text to be shown inplace when user touches the cell. The view with this text must be fullscreen width.
In other words I want to insert a view with text between collection rows. It's desirable that the view appears with animation.

How should I do that? The first ideas I've got are:

1. Divide CollectionView rows into sections and use section footer for this purpose. Make this footer of zero size and show it when needed.
2. Dynamically create full-width cell and insert it at the end of the row where selected item is located.

Both methods seems tricky to me. Maybe there is more straight forward way?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UICollectionViewCell expand/collapse with intrinsic size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528450/uicollectionviewcell-expand-collapse-with-intrinsic-size)

Comment: The second one would work. collection views have insert animations by default. or you can use one of the many available libraries to add animations for insert operation. the only caveat here is figuring out which position to insert it to.

Comment: Chathuranga Silva, not exactly. As I understood that post is about changing size of collection view cell, but I need a little bit different result – I want some additional view to appear under a certain row.